# How to make a path with a String name into a simple String

Tags: actionscript-3

How do i make the path of the item and its name that is given within the **""** into a simple string

what i mean is:
when i just do this

```
var myText:String = new String("pathToImage")
trace(myText)
```

in the outPut window I get this : **pathToImage**.And that is Ok

But can i put double quotes into a string, like this

```
var myText:String = new String(" pathToImage("ImageName") ")
trace(myText)
```

and in the outPut window to get this : **pathToImage("ImageName")**

cause I'm trying this way, but it givems me an error:

```
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before ImageName.
```

So is there a way of doing this?

Comment: I don't understand the question, what is `pathsToImage` in your `trace()` statement for starters?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here but you probably want to escape the double quotes. pathToImage(/"ImageName/")

Comment: lets say its a directory of a Folder.In it I have 5 images with different names.I found i way around this.And solved the problem, but in a very different way.So i still wonder is there a way i can get this **pathToImage("ImageName")** and transform it to a string, or its not possible to have a comment brackets(double quotes) in a string variable.

Comment: tried that @The_asMan but still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it’s enough if you just use string literals. You do not need to call the `String` constructor:

```
var myText:String = "pathToImage";
```

Second, string literals are either quoted with double quotes `"` or single quotes `'`. If you want the quotation character itself as a part of the string, you need to escape it using the escape character `\`. So if you want to have a string `pathToImage("ImageName")`, then you will have to do it like this:

```
var myText:String = "pathToImage(\"ImageName\")";
```

Alternatively, you can also use single quotes here. Using single quotes as the string delimiter allows you to use double quotes within the string without having to escape them. The same applies to single quotes within double-enquoted strings:

```
var myText:String = 'pathToImage("ImageName")';
```